# Scrolling web pages up/down using finger swap on touch screen

Tags: jxbrowser

I have submitted my question when request a evaluation copy of JxBrowser but still not get any response. We are currently using jcef as a web browser in our application and want to evaluate JxBrowser if it given a real web browser experience on touch screen devices. My question is, Is it possible with JxBrowser that user can scroll html pages up/down using finger swape? We need a give same experience to end user as they using web browser on their tablet and can scroll pages up/down with just finger swape. JxBrowser Demo application which i downloaded not providing this kind of facility so any support on this if we need to evaluate this product ?

Thnks

Comment: Still waiting for this reply. Can JxBrowser team update me are they going to implement scrolling in touch screen in linux ?

Comment: I have just checked scrolling using finger on my Dell notebook with touch screen and Windows 8.1, JxBrowser 6.3 Online Demo. It works without any issues. I can scroll up/down using my finger. Could you please provide us with more details about your touch screen device and OS.

Comment: I am using lenovo Tab3 with ubuntu 14.04 and it is not working with that. I tested on window 7 and there it is working.

Comment: I don't have touch device with Ubuntu 14.04 right now. Let me find such device and try JxBrowser on it. It looks like an issue with Linux based touch devices support.